# Sobreescribir metodo logout de Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo activado  en settings `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` para que cuando se cierre el navegador se cierre la sesion.

Tengo una funcion para que cuando se cierre la sesion me haga unas tareas en una tabla de la base de datos, funciona correctamente.

Pero solo funciona cuando se le da a la opcion de LOGOUT, cuando cierro el navegador no funciona.

Entonce pienso, cuando se cierra la sesion al cerrar el navegador, ¿No llama a la funcion LOGOUT? ¿Como podria hacer para obligarle a que pase por LOGOUT y me realice la tarea que quiero?

Comment: No, es que es importante que sepas que roles realiza el navegador y el servidor, al alguien cerrar un navegador no se puede enviar una petición al servidor como notificación por lo cual no hay forma de saber cuando esto sucede, lo que ocurre cuando cierras el navegador es que en la `sessionStorage` (en el caso de chrome) elimina la sesión, y como tal no hace el logout, si no que cuando entra nuevamente, no hay sesión

Comment: No te olvides darle me gusta, es incluso mas importante que aceptarla ;)

Comment: Donde le doy a me gusta?? no me aparece nada....

Comment: @David en la flechita que aparece arriba del cero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es una buena pregunta, pero antes debemos entender por qué no funciona.

Cuando creas la vista logout, lo que estás haciendo es crear una función o clase que se llama cada ves que entras a esa vista y por lo tanto se ejecuta el código que le especificaste. Pero en el caso de expire session at browser close, es diferente por qué la vista ya no entra en juego acá, django toma parte en esto y envia el logout cuando el explorador se cierra.

**Solución**

Bueno acá no estoy tan seguro, pero lo que puedes hacer es modificar directamente en los archivos de django, acá te dejo un link que muestra la función https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py

Puedes tratar agregando el código dentro de la función

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo lo único que he encontrado es hacerlo directamente desde la URL en el archivo `urls.py` 
asi:

```
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    urlpatterns = [

        url(r'^$', inicio, name="inicio"),
        url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout,  {'next_page': '/site/'}, name='logout'),
```

asi puedes dirigir el logout donde tu quieras, Espero que te sirva.